# azure with terraform multiple rules for security group

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to setup multiple security rules for Azure resources.

On AWS, I could just do multiple ingress:

```
  resource "aws_security_group" "mygroup" {
      name        = "mygroup"

      ingress {
        description = "allow all on ssh port"
        from_port   = var.ssh 
        to_port     = var.ssh 
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }

      ingress {
        description = "public port"
        from_port   = var.public
        to_port     = var.public
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks =  ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }

      ingress {
        description = "restricted"
        from_port   = var.restricted
        to_port     = var.restricted
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks =  ["<restricted-ip>/32"]
      }
```

But I do not know how to do this on Azure.

As far as I can see `azurerm_network_security_group` allows only one `security_rule` (is this correct?).

Maybe I would be able to create multiple `azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association` for the same `network_interface_id` but different `network_security_group_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an **azurerm_network_security_rule** resource per rule you add as follows: (example quoted from [azurerm_network_security_rule resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_security_rule.html))

> ```
> resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
>   name                = "acceptanceTestSecurityGroup1"
>   location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
>   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "example" {
>   name                        = "test123"
>   priority                    = 100
>   direction                   = "Outbound"
>   access                      = "Allow"
>   protocol                    = "Tcp"
>   source_port_range           = "*"
>   destination_port_range      = "*"
>   source_address_prefix       = "*"
>   destination_address_prefix  = "*"
>   resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
>   network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.example.name
> }
> ```

Technically, you can define them inline, but you shouldn't as it makes it impossible for other modules to add security group rules if needed. This happens pretty often in practice in my experience, so please don't use inline rule, use separate resources. Your colleagues, including your future self, will thank you.

Comment: Oh I see, so then I can create multiple `azurerm_network_security_rule` instances as I understand. That looks great! Thanks for the tip!